# Best way to filter union of data from 2 tables by value in shared 3rd table

Tags: sql, oracle

For sake of example, let's assume 3 tables:

PHYSICAL_ITEM

```
ID
SELLER_ID
NAME
COST
DIMENSIONS
WEIGHT
```

DIGITAL_ITEM

```
ID
SELLER_ID
NAME
COST
DOWNLOAD_PATH
```

SELLER

```
ID
NAME
```

Item IDs are guaranteed unique across both item tables.  I want to select, in order, with a type label, all item IDs for a given seller.  I've come up with:

Query A

```
SELECT PI.ID AS ID, 'PHYSICAL' AS TYPE
    FROM PHYSICAL_ITEM PI
        JOIN SELLER S ON PI.SELLER_ID = S.ID
    WHERE S.NAME = 'name'
UNION
SELECT DI.ID AS ID, 'DIGITAL' AS TYPE
    FROM DIGITAL_ITEM DI
        JOIN SELLER S ON DI.SELLER_ID = S.ID
    WHERE S.NAME = 'name'
    ORDER BY ID
```

Query B

```
SELECT ITEM.ID, ITEM.TYPE
    FROM (SELECT ID, SELLER_ID, 'PHYSICAL' AS TYPE
              FROM PHYSICAL_ITEM
          UNION
          SELECT ID, SELLER_ID, 'DIGITAL' AS TYPE
              FROM DIGITAL_ITEM) AS ITEM
        JOIN SELLER ON ITEM.SELLER_ID = SELLER.ID
    WHERE SELLER.NAME = 'name'
    ORDER BY ITEM.ID
```

Query A seems like it would be the most efficient, but it also looks unnecessarily duplicative (2 table joins to the same table, 2 where clauses on the same table column).  Query B looks cleaner in a way to me (no duplication), but it also looks much less efficient, since it has a subquery.  Is there a way to get the best of both worlds, so to speak?

Comment: you should test both queries. the second is possibly better as even with the view, Oracle can predicate push into it (i.e. assuming seller has an index on [name, id] it may choose to scan that first, and predicate push the id into the view and join onto two tables before the union is done [and as gordon said, `union all` is right here, as the two sets are not mergable due to the type literal.) the first may scan seller twice. run in sqlplus `set autotrace traceonly` and run each query a couple of times. pay attention to the runtime and IO used on each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In both cases, replace the `union` with `union all`.  `Union` unnecessarily removes duplicates.

I would expect Query A to be more efficient, because the optimizer has more information when doing the join (although I think Oracle is pretty good with using indexes even after a union).  In addition, the first query reduces the amount of data before the union.

This is, however, only an opinion.  The real test is to time the two queries -- multiple times to avoid cache fill delays -- to see which is better.

Comment: Actually, is A even ordering the entire union, or just the digital_item subquery?  Do I need to wrap that in an outter select to be able to order the entire set?

Comment: It is ordering the entire set.  In a union, order by is only allowed at the end of the statement and applies to the whole set.

Comment: Actually, the second query doesn't even seem to work... I get "SQL command not properly ended", and it seems to have to do with aliasing the subquery result.